# Check if a dictionary value is in a string, output = key

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary, python-3.4

Python 3.4

Let's say I've got a dictionary:

```
dict = { "one" : ["abcdefg", "hij"], "two" : ["klmnopq"], "three" : ["rstuvwx", "zyx"] }
```

And I've also got a string:

```
string = "XXXabcdefgXXXhijXXXXXklmnopqXXXXXXzyxXXXXzyxXXXXX"
```

...where "X" stands for other random unimportant letters.

I want to check if the a VALUE of the dictionary is in the string (e.g. if "hij" can be found in String), and if it is, then I want an output that creates a list of all of the different items found in the string.

Something like this:

```
list = []
if dict.value in string:
    list.append(dict.key)
print(list) --> ["one", "one", "two", "three", "three"]
```

What would be the best way to get this sort of result?

Answer (score 0):

You're very close, you have the logic correct and are just missing the loops.

In the outer loop, you need to loop through the keys in the dictionary.

```
for key in dict.keys():
```

In the inner loop, you need to loop through each element in the value list.

```
for value in dict[key]:
```

Here is the full code:

```
key_list = []
for key in dict.keys():
    for value in dict[key]:
        if value in string:
            key_list.append(key)
print(key_list)
```

One other thing to note is that dictionaries do not hold an order, so your result will not be sorted as you would expect.